# svg на всю высоту и ширину

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой блок svg:

```css
html,body, svg {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 300 300">   
  <path id="end" d='M0,0 L300,0 L300,300 L0,300 Z'/>
</svg>
```

Можно ли  растянуть svg на всю высоту и ширину блока  без пробелов по бокам или вверху и внизу? Сейчас он пропорционально меняет свои размеры.

Не обрезать и не ставить на фон, так как в оригинале форма не совсем квадрат, как в  примере, а волнистая поверхность. Просто  для примера:

```css
html,body, svg {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 300 300">   
    <path id="end" d='M0,0 L150,50 L300,0 L250,150 L300,300 L150,250 L0,300 L50,150 Z'/>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы растянуть на всю длину без сохранения пропорций - `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```css
html,body, svg {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
```

```html
 <svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">   
        <path id="end" d='M0,0 L150,50 L300,0 L250,150 L300,300 L150,250 L0,300 L50,150 Z'/>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Во, то что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: Если честно, то пока сама не знаю что хочу)) Модальное или просто блок, на overlay которого будет стоять svg (nbgf nfrjuj https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/EbpPgX) и при открытии этот overlay должен из центра увеличиваться с плавно изменяющимися границами (неровности этого прямоугольника немножко видоизменяются, эффект волны) =)))

Comment: Или, например, что-то типа такого https://codepen.io/giana/pen/gPGGgE но с svg и чтобы не кругами, а как кляксой плавненько расползалось по всему экрану)

Comment: @Клякса на облако похожа и svg формула её простая и анимация будет простая,- расползание на весь экран. Задай вопрос, быстро отвечу.

Comment: @HamSter Плавная  анимация с изменениями формы. Короче, подумай, пожалуйста, как надо, я разные варианты сделаю

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю еще, а то идея, вроде, есть, а вдохновения что-то нет и нет ))

Comment: @HamSter посмотри, перевел статейку по созданию и анимации облаков https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754793/28748 можно сделать другую анимацию, как ты задумывала с изменением размеров, краев и т.д

Comment: Вот идея - https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/JMWEWe?editors=1010
НО, не могу реализовать плавность, чтобы визуально казалось, будто клякса растекается по экрану, не хватает эластичности и плавности. 
ИЛИ хотя бы по плавности как тут https://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/qLxAB?limit=all&page=2&q=morph

Comment: @HamSter посмотрел, интересно, ты права, надо над плавностью поработать. Вечерком код повнимательней заценю. Настроение улучшается? Раз новые идеи в голову приходят :)

Comment: настроение - no comment, идея это выдавливание последнего из себя