# Создание responsive формы облака

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь создать в CSS респонсивную форму облака  для проекта.

Хочу не делать этого с изображениями, `CSS` или встроенным `SVG` из-за HTTP-запросов и требованиями к отзывчивости.

Форма, о которой идет речь, будет такой: (но может быть и похожей - небольшие изменения / улучшения были бы интересны):

Я нашел оба этих вопроса, но они, похоже, не соответствуют моим конкретным потребностям:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- [How to fill a text with color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785330/how-to-fill-a-text-with-color-using-css/)
- [CSS apply border to a cloud shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508834/css-apply-border-to-a-cloud-shape/)

Пытался, но не смог создать облако с `border` или `box-shadow` и мне необходимо знать, возможно ли это с помощью CSS или в качестве альтернативы, встроенный SVG.
 Я также знаю, что Canvas тоже вариант, но я предпочел бы держаться подальше от него, поскольку это может быть довольно сложно.

Это моя неудачная попытка:

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
}

.cloud {
  width: 15%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  border-radius: 65px;
  box-shadow: black 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.cloud:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: -60px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  background: white;
}
.cloud:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  left: 50px;
  top: -30px;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud"></div>
```

Как вы можете видеть, у меня возникают проблемы с отзывчивостью и вычислением того, какие должно быть высоты / ширины.

Я также пытаюсь сократить количество кода `HTML` до абсолютного минимума, и поэтому я бы предпочел использовать один `div` или короткий SVG-код.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Creating a responsive cloud shape]https://stackoverflow.com/q/30919053/7394871) от участника  [@Stewartside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889988/stewartside).</sub>

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30919053/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое подойдет?

```css
.cloud, .cloudshadow {
 width: 350px; height: 120px;
 background: #3498db;
 border-radius: 100px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 150px 50px;
}
.cloud:after, .cloud:before, .cloudshadow:after, .cloudshadow:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background: #3498db;
 z-index: 1
}
.cloudshadow, .cloudshadow:after, .cloudshadow:before {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #2c3e50;
    z-index: -99;
}
.cloud:after, .cloudshadow:after {
 width: 100px; height: 100px;
 top: -50px; left: 50px;
 border-radius: 100px;
}
.cloud:before, .cloudshadow:before  {
 width: 180px; height: 180px;
 top: -90px; right: 50px;
 border-radius: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud">
    <div class="cloudshadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T, тогда почему бы не поставить галочку :)

Answer (score 4):

Форма облака может быть создана с использованием `SVG` с одним элементом `path` в коде.

SVG по своей природе масштабируются без каких-либо искажений формы.

### Создание фигуры

Команды, используемые при рисовании фигуры и их значение:

- `M 25,60` - Эта команда перемещает перо в точку, которая на 25
  пикселей правее «начала координат (0,0)» на «оси X» и «60 пикселей»
  перед «началом по оси Y». (Примечание: команда написана в верхнем
  регистре, что указывает на абсолютное значение, а не на
  относительное).
- `a 20,20 1 0,0 0,40` - Эта команда создает дугу, радиусы `X` и `Y`
  которой 20px. Начальная точка дуги равна `(25,60)`, а конечная точка
  равна `(25 100)`
- `h 50` - Эта команда рисует горизонтальную линию, которая находится
  на расстоянии `50px`  относительно начальной точки. Поскольку
  параметр относительный, то конечная точка будет равна `(75 100)`.
- `a 20,20 1 0,0 0, -40` - Подобно второй команде, эта создает другую
  дугу, радиусы которой равны `20px` на любой оси, а ее конечная точка
  находится на 40 пикселей раньше, чем  предыдущая точка. Поэтому, по
  существу это создало бы дугу от `(75 100)` до `(75,60)`. Эта и вторая
  команда вместе образуют дуги с двух сторон облака.
- `a 10,10 1 0,0 -15, -10` - Еще одна команда дуги для создания одной
  части изогнутой вершины облака. Радиусы составляют 10px, а дуга будет
  от `(75,60)` до `(60,50)`
- `a 15,15 1 0,0 -35,10` - Последняя дуга для завершения облака.
  Радиусы 15px, а дуга будет от `(60,50)` до `(25,60)`. `(25,60)` Это
  была исходная, отправная точка и, таким образом, она завершает форму.
- `z` - Команда закрытия пути.

```css
svg {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
path {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
path:hover {
  fill: aliceblue;
  stroke: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 105 105'>
  <path d='M 25,60 
           a 20,20 1 0,0 0,40 
           h 50 
           a 20,20 1 0,0 0,-40 
           a 10,10 1 0,0 -15,-10 
           a 15,15 1 0,0 -35,10  
           z' />
</svg>
```

### Преимущества использования SVG

- Их легко создавать и поддерживать
- Команды достаточно просты для понимания и не требуют сложного
  позиционирования или `hacks`
- По умолчанию они масштабируемы
- Нет дополнительных HTTP-запросов, если SVG является встроенным
- Лучше контролировать дуги, их радиусы и т.д.
- Эффекты `Hover`, как показано в приведенном ниже примере, могут быть
  ограничены, чтобы запускаться только тогда, когда мышь находится в
  границах формы.
- Дополнительные эффекты могут быть добавлены беспорядочно. То есть вы
  можете имитировать поведение фигуры на экране и т.д.

### Дополнительные эффекты - анимация облачного рисования

Ниже приведен фрагмент кода с анимацией рисования облака, где путь рисуется путем постепенного уменьшения значения параметра `path` - `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения до нуля.
Начальное значение смещения равно общей длине пути, которая вычисляется с использованием метода `getTotalLength ().`
У облачной формы также есть тень размытия.

Анимация достигается с помощью [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var offset;
  var path = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];
  var len = path.getTotalLength();

  function paint() {
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = len;
    path.style.strokeDasharray = len + ',' + len;
    animate();
  }

  function animate() {
    if (!offset) offset = len;
    offset -= 0.5;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
    if (offset < 0)
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
    else anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      animate();
    });
  }

  paint();
};
```

```css
svg {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
}
path {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
path:hover {
  fill: aliceblue;
  stroke: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 105 105'>
  <filter id='shadow'>
    <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='2' />
    <feOffset dx='2' dy='0' result='blur' />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in='blur' />
      <feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic' />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <path d='M 25,60 
           a 20,20 1 0,0 0,40 
           h 50 
           a 20,20 1 0,0 0,-40 
           a 10,10 1 0,0 -15,-10 
           a 15,15 1 0,0 -36,10  
           z' filter='url(#shadow)' />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Creating a responsive cloud shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919326/7394871) от участника  [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry).</sub>